# Generating random distinct pair with no diagonals

Tags: java, random

I want to generate two random pair of integer with no duplicate in an array of length 8 and I don't want any pair in the same diagonal

```
public static int[] randomizer(int[] v){
    int [] a= new int[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*9);

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                i--;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    a[0] = v[0] ;
    return a;
}
```

This is what I have done so far.

Comment: Can you provide a small example with some numbers? It is not that easy to understand what you mean with the diagonal stuff.

Comment: Give us example having your expected output

Comment: "two random pair" = 4 numbers but the array has length 8... and a diagonal???

Comment: I think the diagonal has to do with the *v-array* but we will need to wait for OP to clarify with an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to generate **two random sequences of integers** with the length of **8** each. Both sequences should not have any number in common, so you want **16 unique random numbers**.

Next comes the requirement with the diagonal part - I don't get it. Please specify it more precice, a small example would be nice.

---

Meanwhile let's solve the first part. Generating 16 unique integers is quite easy. You generate a random number and memorize it. If it was already generated before than reject it and try again. For a fast **contains** access and **add** you should use a `HashSet`. Let's take a look at the following snippet:

```
public static Set<Integer> randomUniqueNumbers(int amount, int upperBound){
    final HashSet<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
    final Random rnd = new Random();

    // Stop when generated enough numbers
    while (numbers.size() < amount) {
        final int randomNumber = rnd.nextInt(upperBound);
        // Try to add it to the set.
        // The method will do nothing if the number was contained already.
        numbers.add(randomNumber);
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

The method will generate **amount** many unique numbers and store them in a `Set<Integer>` that can be iterated and used by your method. The numbers are between `0` (*inclusive*) and `upperBound` (*exclusive*) like with `(int)(Math.random() * upperBound)` you used.
Note that it is possible that the *while-loop* does not halt, for example when extremely unlucky or the given parameters contradict. If that is a problem you can count the number of unsuccessful tries and abort with **break** once it goes beyond a defined upper limit of tries.

---

You want **16** of those numbers and store them in two **arrays of length 8** each. Here's is how you can do this:

```
final int[] firstSequence = new int[8];
final int[] secondSequence = new int[8];

// Exchange with the correct upperBound, I assume it is 9
final Set<Integer> numbers = randomUniqueNumbers(16, 9);

Iterator<Integer> numberIter = numbers.iterator();
// Fill the first sequence
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    firstSequence[i] = numberIter.next();
}
// Fill the second sequence
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    secondSequence[i] = numberIter.next();
}
```

I think that covers most of your question. Please specify more precise what is missing and I will update the answer.
Also note that `randomUniqueNumbers(16, 9)` can not halt. It will run forever since it is not possible to generate **16 different numbers** out of `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}` which are only **9 numbers**. Also note that when both parameters are close it will be drastically faster to use another approach where you pre-define `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}` and now just permutate this set and then iterate it, like `Collections.shuffle(numbers)` and then `for(Integer number : numbers) { ... }`.